# Capture exception thrown by Hystrix fallback?

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm designing a service facade and I have a method signature that looks like this:

```java
public Policy getPolicy(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException
```

If nothing bad happens then a Policy object (simple POJO) is returned. If the requested policy is not found then a checked exception PolicyNotFoundException is thrown (just as a reference - we follow [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effective-exceptions-092345.html) when it comes to best practices on exception handling within an application).

The layer above the service facade layer (in this case a [Spring MVC RestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)) knows how to handle such a PolicyNotFoundException and return an appropriate payload.

I'm trying to incorporate this into a HystrixCommand by doing something like this:

```java
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "PolicyService", fallbackMethod = "getPolicySafe", ignoreExceptions = { PolicyNotFoundException.class })
public Policy getPolicy(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException {
    LOGGER.info("Getting policy {}", policyId);

    // Simulate some error condition for testing purposes
    throw new RuntimeException("Something happened!");
}

private Policy getPolicySafe(long policyId, Throwable t) throws PolicyNotFoundException {
    LOGGER.warn("Falling back to circuit-breaker for getting policy {}", policyId, t);
    throw new PolicyNotFoundException(policyId);
}
```

Basically I want my circuit breaker to simply behave as if the policy wasn't found by the original lookup. The problem I'm having with this though is the exception I throw from the fallback method is getting lost in translation somewhere. The exception I end up seeing in the layer above is the RuntimeException thrown by the command method and not the exception thrown by the fallback method. Is there a way around this? I don't want to change the contract of my original method either nor do I want the layer above this to know anything other than to have to catch PolicyNotFoundException in the case a policy isn't found. Whatever is needed here should be captured within this service facade layer.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So based on the link @spencergibb gave - I may have found a solution after upgrading to Hystrix 1.5.7. This code works as expected

PolicyRestController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/policies")
public class PoliciesApi {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PoliciesApi.class);

  @Autowired
  private PolicyService policyService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{policyId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaTypes.POLICY_JSON_VALUE, MediaTypes.POLICY_XML_VALUE })
  public Policy getPolicy(@PathVariable long policyId) {
    try {
      // This just shown for simplicity. There is more to this method (input validation/etc)
      return this.policyService.getPolicy(policyId);
    }
    catch (PolicyNotFoundException ex) {
      // NotFoundException is a RuntimeException annotated with @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
      // So the service returns a 404 to the client
      LOGGER.info("Policy {} wasn't found", ex.getPolicyId(), ex);
      throw new NotFoundException(String.format("Policy %s was not found", ex.getPolicyId()));
    }
  }
}
```

PolicyService.java

```java
public interface PolicyService {
    @Cacheable("allPolicies")
    public List<Policy> getPolicies();

    @Cacheable("policies")
    public Policy getPolicy(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException;
}
```

PolicyServiceImpl.java:

```java
@Service
public class PolicyServiceImpl implements PolicyService {
  @HystrixCommand(groupKey = "PolicyService", fallbackMethod = "getPolicySafe", ignoreExceptions = { PolicyNotFoundException.class })
  public Policy getPolicy(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException {
    LOGGER.info("Getting policy {}", policyId);

    // Simulate some error condition for testing purposes
    throw new RuntimeException("Something happened!");
  }

  @HystrixCommand(groupKey = "PolicyService", ignoreExceptions = { PolicyNotFoundException.class }, raiseHystrixExceptions = { HystrixException.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION })
  private Policy getPolicySafe(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException {
    // Here is we hit our fallback we want to log a warning & simply act as if the policy wasn't found by throwing the same contingency exception as the API does
    LOGGER.warn("Falling back to circuit-breaker for getting policy {}", policyId);

    throw new PolicyNotFoundException(policyId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of hystrix. "If command has a fallback then only first exception that trigers fallback logic will be propagated to caller"

See the error propagation section [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica#error-propagation).

Comment: Right I understand that. Is there a way to alter that behavior?

Comment: There was some discussion about exceptions here https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1344

Comment: Thanks for the link - I hadn't seen that. While this is a step in the right direction it does not completely solve the issue. The service facade layer of the application is where all of this hystrix "stuff" comes into play. This solution "pollutes" the layer above & makes the caller of the service facade layer have to know specific details that Hystrix is involved by having to catch HystrixRuntimeException, look for a fallback exception (which is generally a FallbackInvocationException) and then have to read the cause from that.

Comment: Actually I think I may have solved it using the solution provided in that like that @spencergibb gave. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Actually that's not true, the project wiki is out-of-date because the behavior was changed in this PR: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/pull/1389 so that we need to update the docs

Comment: Upon further testing this seems to only work until the circuit is open - then the HystrixRuntimeException propagates back up to the next layer

Answer (score 1):

While your solution might work for you I've noticed some weirdness in your code (I can't check my assumptions so I would like to ask you to check this).

1. Try to avoid using checked exceptions in your code because it's
   awkward to maintain.
2. Based on your code you will never catch
   "PolicyNotFoundException" since you're using raiseHystrixExceptions = { HystrixException.RUNTIME_EXCEPTION } which means that you won't to get       your custom exception so that HystrixRuntimeException will be propagated. Try to rewrite your code as follows so it should
   simplify the code and maybe fix some of your problems:

---

```
@Service
public class PolicyServiceImpl implements PolicyService {
  @HystrixCommand(groupKey = "PolicyService", fallbackMethod = "getPolicySafe")
  public Policy getPolicy(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException {
    LOGGER.info("Getting policy {}", policyId);
    throw new PolicyNotFoundException(); // throw real PolicyNotFoundException if policy is absent for the given id
  }

  @HystrixCommand(groupKey = "PolicyService")
  private Policy getPolicySafe(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException {
    // Here is we hit our fallback we want to log a warning & simply act as if the policy wasn't found by throwing the same contingency exception as the API does
    LOGGER.warn("Falling back to circuit-breaker for getting policy {}", policyId);

    throw new PolicyNotFoundException(policyId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. This still doesn't work in the case the circuit is open. When the circuit is open the HystrixRuntimeException is propagated up to the caller (in my case a Spring MVC RestController). This "pollutes" my RestController class by having to include a catch of HystrixRuntimeException. I'd like to keep all hystrix-related "stuff" in the service facade layer where it belongs.

Comment: @Eric So logically it's correct because the exception is raised by hystrix platform. it's expected behavior so that you have to catch HystrixRuntimeException in this case.

Comment: It just feels "dirty" though that some other layer in your application needs to know that Hystrix is even involved. If I have an interface between my RestController & service facade layers that says

`public Policy getPolicy(long policyId) throws PolicyNotFoundException`

the caller of that method shouldn't have to also know that maybe Hystrix is in the picture and may need to catch a HystrixRuntimeException & unwrap the PolicyNotFoundException from it...

Comment: Just to make it clear: circuit breaker is a platform feature , so if a command rejected because of circuit breaker, time out and etc. it's not user exception , you cannot throw PolicyNotFOundExcepton in this case because it's logically incorrect and technically impossible because platform doesn't know about client exceptions. We can think about adding some exception handler which catches hystrix exceptions and wraps it in custom ones.

Comment: When the circuit is "open" - I assume the fallback method still gets called right? Shouldn't the behavior be the same if the circuit is closed and the command fails vs if the circuit is open?

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
@Component
public class HystrixClient {

  @HystrixCommand(ignoreExceptions = {ClientArgumentException.class})
  public POJO getPojo(String id)
        throws ClientNoDataFoundException, ClientArgumentException, ClientGeneralException {

    //call my service and return POJO
  }
}

@Component
public TrueClientUsedForAnotherSerivce {

  @Autowired
  HystrixClient hystrixClient;

 public POJO getPojo(String id)
        throws ClientNoDataFoundException, ClientArgumentException, ClientGeneralException, ClientOpenCircuitException {
    try {           
        POJO result = hystrixClient.getCellular(id);            

        return result;
    }
    catch(HystrixRuntimeException e) {
        LOG.debug("The circuit is open");
        throw new ClientOpenCircuitException("Open circuit");
    }
}
```

It only works if @HystrixCommand method is in another class.

Comment: Add some description on your code. Logic would help much better than a piece of code